# How to execute POST

Tags: load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

Using curl I have:

```
$ curl -v -d "userName=user1&password=passwd1&language=en" http://myhost:23094/api/v2/authToken
...
> POST /api/v2/authToken HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: myhost:23094
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 39
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 39 out of 39 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I try to build a yandex tank script using this query:

My load.ini:

```
[phantom]
address=my.ip.v4.here
port=8094
rps_schedule=line(1, 10, 1m)
ammo_type=uripost
```

My ammo.txt

```
133 login
POST /api/v2/authToken HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: tank
Host: somemyhost.com
Content-Length: 39

userName=user1&password=passwd1&language=en
```

When I run `yandex-tank ammo.txt`, I get the 400 Bad Request error.
It seems to me, that tank can't use the body parameters. How to make it use them? What do I do wrong?

Comment: Please refrain from using profanity on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Asaph Sorry, I didn't see this f-string, when I moved my sources here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ammo is not in `uripost` format. Don't specify ammo_type at all and it should work properly. If you want to use `uripost` format, specify your headers in `load.ini` and write something like the following in your ammo file:

```
39 /api/v2/authToken login

userName=user1&password=passwd1&language=en
```

Here is the [description](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#uri-post-style) of the `uripost` format.